# .htaccess 301 Redirect - Regex Exact Number Only

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Hi Im trying to do a whole load of 301 redirects for a new website that has an existing site, all the old product page urls have a product id on them so im trying to match this using a reg exp pattern, but the problem is its matching numbers that are inside the big number for example

Product ID 20463, is being matched to Product ID 463

heres an example of somethings ive tried:

```
RewriteRule .*\/category-folder\/.*(-20463)\.html htpps://www.example.com/productpage/etc/etc
```

ive also tried it with a word boundry as:

```
RewriteRule .*\/category-folder\/.*(\b20463\b)\.html https://etc...
```

basically it should match the folder name , the product id and end with .html

Testing on reg ex playgrounds my examples seem to work well, but not on the apache server? where it matches the smaller number inside as the example above.

https://www.example.co.uk/category/view-product-20463.html

Any Help Appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Sorry, Ive added an example now in my question above.

Comment: :( Its still loading the redirect that is associated with RewriteRule ^category/.*-463\.html$

Comment: are you serious? if it was any more clear I could put fish in it..Actually It seams the .htaccess file is not refreshing, so I need to just fathom that out.

Thanks anyway :)